# Is there any CalDAV+CardDAV server implementation available in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, caldav, carddav

Is there any `CalDAV+CardDAV` server implementation/open-source projects available in .NET?
I've searched a lot and couldn't find any server implementations.
Thanks in advance...